# Alfresco share storage space

Tags: alfresco, alfresco-share

I have 10 GB of files in another server. Now I need to upload the files to the alfresco share.
Do I need to manually drag and drop these files to the alfresco share repository?
Is there any other option like mapping these files so alfresco adds them automatically?

Comment: It's better to go to the Alfresco support forums. This question gets asked quite often. Short answer: zip them up and import them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are different options here:

1. Make use of Alfresco's Virtual FileSystem capabilities and import your documents via CIFS or FTP: http://docs.alfresco.com/4.2/topic/com.alfresco.enterprise.doc/concepts/fileserv-subsystem-intro.html
2. Use Alfresco's bulk import tool: http://docs.alfresco.com/4.2/topic/com.alfresco.enterprise.doc/concepts/Bulk-Import-Tool.html
3. Use any other Alfresco migrations tools like: Xenit move2alf or fme migration-center

Comment: What happen to the memory space will it take more? Can I delete the old files after uploading to alfresco?

Comment: taken memory while importing depends mainly on the number of parallel import threads. So, it depends on your general procedure.
What do you mean with "old files"? If you're referencing your source system files then it is up to you to decide if you can delete them.

Comment: I tried mounting via webdav in windows 7 64 bit. I gave the unc as `\\pc1@8080\alfresco\webdav\` but I getting error mounting